# IOS 8 UItableView Swipe To delete

Tags: uitableview, ios8, delete-row, swipe-gesture

I have UIviewController which contains a UITableView , it's a very simple code , I just want to swipe one cell and show more and delete and handle these two events , this is my very simple class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let deleteClosure = { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
    println("Delete closure called")
}

let moreClosure = { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
    println("More closure called")
}



override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{
    var moreAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default , title: "More") { (action : UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        println("more")
    }
    moreAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        println("delete")
    }

    return [moreAction , deleteAction]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if (editingStyle == .Delete)
    {
        println("delete1")

    }
    if(editingStyle == .Insert)
    {
        println("insert")

    }

}
```

the editActionsForRowAtIndexPath function get called but none of the RowActions shows up !
what's the problem ? ,

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something in the handlers of your custom buttons.

For example, with a custom delete button (and just to change its label and background color), you would do somehting like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let button = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: NSLocalizedString("TitleOfDeleteButton", comment: "Delete"), handler: { (rowAction, indexPath) -> Void in
        self.tableView(self.tableView!, commitEditingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    })
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    return [button]
}
```

Also, don't forget that this method of the UITableViewDelegate protocol came only with iOS8